# Spring Security cannot locate NamespaceHandler

Tags: spring, spring-security

While trying to set up `Spring Security` I always come across this error which I still don't know how to handle:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [security.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security.xml]
```

By coding this, I strict followed the `Spring Security` [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/). In SO, I've also searched for similar questions but none of them solved my problem.

As far as I see, the error is mainly caused by two things: 
First, `Spring` is unable to import security.xml and second, `Spring` cannot locate its `NamespaceHandler` for XML schema namespace. 
Am I missing some dependencies or why is `Spring` unable to find its `NamespaceHandler`?

I'm using `Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE` with `Spring Security 4.0.2.RELEASE`.

So, here's my code:

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
        <form-login />
        <logout />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And in **applicationContext.xml** I simply import security.xml

```
<import resource="security.xml" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you also add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

add this underneath the ContextLoaderListener declaration in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I just added the two dependencies but nothing changed... got still the same error. What I don't understand is, that the required spring-security-config.jar do exist in my Libraries but still got that BeanDefinitionParsingException.

Comment: @MaxWell I edited my answer can you try with this new suggestion

Comment: Thanks again...doesn't work... . But now I get some additional error information: Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security.xml].

Comment: I just noticed that you have in your security.xml namespace 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd' but you are using spring 4.0.2 and spring-security4.0.2 no? it might be related to this issue you are having, other than that I'm not sure what is wrong here. I also edited my answer again by removing       'classpath:security.xml' from the web.xml as the applicationContext.xml imports the security.xml as a resource

Comment: referencing the spring-beans-3.0 could be causing a conflict as you have spring 4 jars in your pom/library folder, so try without declaring version numbers in the security namespace, i.e. follow the same pattern as you have with the spring-security namespace declaration)

Comment: Thanks for updating, I also noticed to remove the 'classpath:security.xml' from the web.xml and I also followed your advice to declare security namespaces without versions - again, nothing changed. I always get this damn exception that Spring is unable to locate NamespaceHandler. So, now I've really no idea of what trying next... for me, it all seems right.

Comment: yeah I'm lost as well, everything looks fine, the only thing I can think of is that when your application gets deployed to the server some for whatever reason some jars (specifically the spring-security jars in this case) are not being deployed along with the rest of the project

Comment: I solved it! I set up my whole project completely from scratch and copied all files except security.xml and then everything worked as expected. Don't know what was going wrong until now... . @smoggers thank you so much for your efforts!